# MySQL Multiple ID reference

Tags: mysql

I have two tables the first one is a breeds table

```
CREATE TABLE `breeds` (
 `breedID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`breedID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The second table is a owners table

```
CREATE TABLE `owners` (
 `ownerID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `First` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
 `Last` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
 `breeds` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ownerID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I want the owner table to reflect what breeds it owns by showing the breedID in the breeds column but I want the owner to be able to have multiple. How would I do this?

Comment: You need a join table, an intermediate table that relates many owners to many breeds.

Comment: You need to have an [associative table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two tables, you need three for a many-to-many relationships. You need to add the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ownerBreeds` (
 `ownerBreedID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `breedID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `ownerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ownerBreedID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and remove the `breeds` column from the `owners` table. This will allow for an owner owning multiple breeds as well as a breed being owned by multiple owners.

Comment: It would be wise to add foreign key constraints on `breedID` and `ownerID`.

Comment: @BenM That it would be.